# Bedeutung des Verbs "grasen"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Ich möchte einen Satz aus einem Lied übersetzen.

> Bald grase ich am Neckar, bald grase ich am Rhein

Das Problem ist, ich weiß nicht, wie das Verb 'grasen' in dem Satz gemeint ist. Ich habe das Gefühl, dass es nicht um weiden geht.

Comment: http://www.liederlexikon.de/lieder/bald_gras_ich_am_neckar

Comment: Das Lied hatte ich auch gerade gefunden. Und das grasen dort bedeutet tatsächlich weiden, im Sinne von 'sich ernähren', 'seinen Lebensunterhalt verdienen'.

Comment: Worauf basiert denn Dein Gefühl, dass es nicht das genannte Synonym ist?

Comment: Ich hoffe, es ist nicht 'weiden' im Sinne von 'Gras essen' gemeint...

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu ich dachte nur, Menschen weiden ja nicht. Es sei denn das Lied ist von einem Bullen :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dein Gefühl ist wohl richtig.

Die Herren Grimm erwähnen in ihrem Wörterbuch eine interessante Nebenbedeutung von *grasen*:

> … das grasen der mädchen und frauen ist ein beliebtes literarisches
>   motiv im zusammenhang mit liebesabenteuern; vgl. auch unter b: (einem
>   mönch) ein iunges meydlein …

Diese – im heutigen Deutsch nicht mehr verwendete – Bedeutung dürfte hier gemeint sein.

Die wörtliche Bedeutung wurde ja schon erwähnt.

Und weil das *Grasen* (also das „richtige“, das tägliche Futterholen für die Tiere) traditionell eine Beschäftigung der jungen Frauen war – auch dazu gibt’s eine Erklärung im Grimm –, kann man darüber hinaus stark vermuten, dass die Erzählerperson im Lied eben eine junge Frau ist, die sich ihre Liebhaber vorzugsweise an Flüssen sucht.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Da ich über das Lied aus dem Video (https://youtu.be/9LhvOe0hv0E) erfahren habe, bin ich davon ausgegangen, dass das ein Mann 'bald grasen' wird :)

Comment: Nur der Vollständigkeit halber: Das *bald* im Lied dürfte hier die heute nicht mehr verwendete Bedeutung von *manchmal* haben.

Comment: Aber sicher wird *bald …, bald …* heute noch verwendet.

Comment: Aber bald nicht mehr ;) . Nein, im Ernst - Ich kenne *bald..bald* im Sinne von "mal hier, mal da" oder "manchmal" nicht aus meinem Sprachgebrauch.

Answer (score 2):

> Was hilft mir das Grasen,
>   denn d'Sichel nicht schneid't;

Aus dem Kontext mit der Sichel würde ich denken, dass *grasen* hier *mähen* bedeutet.